# PyAutoGui Module is not running (Yes it is installed)

Tags: python, pyautogui

I recently installed Pyautogui, and yet it is not working. Import pyautogui is working, and the commands that do not involve moving the mouse is working (e.g, getting the length and width of the screen).
However, when I tried to do, for example:

```
import pyautogui as pti
pti.moveTo(500, 500, duration=0.25)
```

It does not work.
However, things like

```
a = pti.size()
print(str(a))
```

Do work. Can someone please explain this? Thanks.

FYI, I code on IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. It was because I had my mouse in :).
Sorry for posting the question.

Comment: Too bad, I wanted to tell you. :)